# I need 2 different heights applied to 2 different fieldset tags

Tags: css

What I am using in CSS is

```
form fieldset
{
    height : 300px;    
}
```

but I have

```
<fieldset><legend>ONE</legend></fieldset>`

<fieldset><legend>TWO</legend></fieldset>
```

The problem is both field sets are being applied the same height.

Is there a way to apply different heights to different fieldsets from CSS. I am not looking for inline styles which I know how to apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give each fieldset an ID if you will only use each ONCE, otherwise use a class

```
<fieldset id="f1">
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="f2">
</fieldset>
```

OR

```
<fieldset class="bluefieldset"> 
</fieldset> 
<fieldset class="grayfieldset"> 
</fieldset>
```

A class signifies that many elements can use it.  with Id in W3C it is the standard that the Id attribute be unique to the page

In CSS you reference a class like

```
.bluefieldset{}
```

OR

```
fieldset.bluefieldset{}
```

for the ID you use the hash like

```
#f1
```

OR

```
fieldset#f1{}
```

Comment: dont use colours in class names, if you ever change the colours the CSS won't make sense

Comment: What if it is a blue fieldset though.  If I change the color I would obviously create a new Css Class i.e. RedFieldset then I have two useful classes. One bluefieldset and one redfieldset as I may need both

Answer (score 0):

Use css :first-child selector (http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_first-child.asp)

This doesn't work in IE6